# Different menus for different account types in navigation menu

Tags: java, html, css, spring, freemarker

In my Spring project, using freemarker, I have this menu:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navigation">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav topnav bold">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="<@spring.url '/admin/home' />"><@spring.message "label.home" /></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown active"><a href="#"><@spring.message "label.adminPanel" /> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu bold">
                            <li><a href="<@spring.url '/admin/manageaccount' />"><@spring.message "label.manageAccounts" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="<@spring.url '/admin/editMeForm' />"><@spring.message "label.myAccount" /></a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="<@spring.url '/j_spring_security_logout' />"><@spring.message "label.logout" /> </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I want to hide some elements for Guests and insert others if the user is a Client, Employee, Admin etc.

I added iny my page:

```
<#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />
```

and

```
                            <@security.authorize  access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                            <li class="dropdown active"><a href="#"><@spring.message "label.adminPanel" /> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu bold">
                                    <li><a href="<@spring.url '/admin/manageaccount' />"><@spring.message "label.manageAccounts" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<@spring.url '/admin/editMeForm' />"><@spring.message "label.myAccount" /></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </@security.authorize>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spring security and depending on the user role you can show/hide the part of your menu.

`<@security.authorize  access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">`

Comment: I added this, but i get errors. Added stackTrace in firstPost.

Comment: You need to enable use-expression in your spring security config.
`<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" >.....</http>`